# database migration in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Recently I got a question about rails3.1's migration.Here is the one of the migration file code.

```
def change
  create_table :books do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.decimal :price
  end
end
```

Now I need to add a foreign key, let's say comment_id, I used to create another migration and use add_column method in it to get it done.

But since we are in rail3.1,so I thought there might be a new way to do it.so I alter the code

```
def change
  create_table :books do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.decimal :price
    t.references :comment
  end
end
```

OK,now I run rake db:migrate and nothing happens. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you run `rake db:rollback` before running `rake db:migrate`?  You need to roll back the migration before reapplying it with the changes.

Comment: Also make sure u remove `t.references :comment` when you run db:rollback

Comment: Would rake db:rollback drop the data that previously exist the database?

Comment: Probably yes,  If you can't have that, then you need to create a new migration `rails generate migration AddReferencesToBooks comment:references` instead of changing the existing migration.

Comment: yeah,looks like we still need the old way